# Array[index + 1] causing the program FATAL error

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have integer count which is my array index, lets assume count is equal to 5, so my `arrayWeight[count]` index/count is equal to 5.
The values inside the array are doubles and all the 5 cells in the array are used and contains values.

Now I'm willing to add all the `arrayWeight[]` values into `DataPoint[]` array, though the index in `DataPoint[]` is equal to 6 (count + 1).
and the sixth index in the array is used outside of the loop as you can see below:

```
    double[] arrayWeight = new double[count]; // Array of user weight
    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[count+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // Array weight is inserted into datapoints y and i is the x so the graph will follow the (x,y)
            dp[i] = new DataPoint(i, arrayWeight[i]);
            Log.d("ArrayWeight", "equals: " + arrayWeight[i]);
            Log.d("Array", "equals: " + i);
        }
    dp[count+1] = new DataPoint(count+1, db.getDetails().getWeight());
    return dp;
```

I can tell you the code is working when I remove the +1 from the index and use only count, but I need to use count + 1 so I can add another value to `DataPoint[]` array.

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.none.myapplication, PID: 12760
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.none.myapplication/com.none.myapplication.MainActivity}:  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
```

How to create array[index+1] in the correct way, so it wont return fatal error?

Comment: your array goes `0-5` mean `6` elements , so the max position in your array is `5` not `6`

Comment: Why do you think the number equal to the array length (or "size") is a valid index?

Comment: @PavneetSingh I'm adding the sixth element after the loop.

Comment: Your array `DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[count+1];` has size `count+1` so its max index is `count` but in `dp[count+1] = new DataPoint(count+1, db.getDetails().getWeight());` you are trying to use index which is out of `[0, count]` bounds.

Comment: @Tom So how should I write it?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `dp[count]` insted of dp[count+1] in this line:

```
dp[count+1] = new DataPoint(count+1, db.getDetails().getWeight());
```

because indices in dp will be 0 to count

Answer (score 0):

The index should be `count` instead of `count + 1`. The last index in the for loop was `count - 1`. See that the loop is `i < count`.

Answer (score 0):

dp[count+1] is not valid in your code. Array indexes start from 0, so if your count=5, count+1 = 6. So length of dp is 6, but indexes start from 0 to 5.

You should do dp[count] after your for loop to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Array `dp` has `count + 1` indices, so the highest index is `count` (Because first is zero).
Replace

```
dp[count+1] = new DataPoint(count+1, db.getDetails().getWeight());
```

with

```
dp[count] = new DataPoint(count, db.getDetails().getWeight());
```

to fix your problem.